# 3 Button showing and hiding text for HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are three buttons (`button 1`, `button 2`, and `button 3`) and three texts, (`text 1`, `text 2`, and `text 3`). Each text is right under its corresponding button. Imagine it like so,

```
[button 1] 
..text 1..
[button 2] 
..text 2.. 
[button 3]
..text 3..
```

The following conditions should apply,

- When the document loads all texts should be hidden.
- Clicking on a button who's corresponding text is hidden should show that text.
- Clicking on a button who's corresponding text is shown should hide that text.
- At most one text should be showing at any given time.
- And if a text is shown, and I click the respective button, that text will be hidden. For example, if I clicked button 1, and text 1 shows. And I click button 1 again, text 1 should be hidden.

How can I achieve this effect?

I tried to do this just with 2 buttons, but I couldn't figure it out.

```
var show1 = false; 
var show2 = false;
function showDearPresidentText() {
    if(show1 == false && show2 == false) {
        document.getElementById("text1").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("text2").style.display="none";
        show1 = true; 
    }
    else if(show1 == true && show2 == false) {
        document.getElementById("text1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("text2").style.display="none";
        show1 = false; 
    }
    else if(show1 == false && show2 == true) {
        document.getElementById("text1").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("text2").style.display="none";
        show1 = true; 
    }
}
function showDearReaderText() {
    if(show1 == false && show2 == false) {
        document.getElementById("text1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("text2").style.display="block";
        show2 = true; 
    }
    else if(show1 == true && show2 == false) {
        document.getElementById("text1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("text2").style.display="block";
        show1 = true; 
    }
    else if(show1 == false && show2 == true) {
        document.getElementById("text1").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("text2").style.display="block";
        show1 = false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the complete code with attempts to solve the problem

Comment: I wrote the three button logic on paper. But I tried the two button as well in code. Here it is.

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: yup. can do. of course.

Comment: See my code will definitely work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.css()` , [Next Adjacent Selector ("prev + next")](https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) with context set to `this` within `click` handler , `.not()`

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {
  var div = $("+ div", this);   
  div.css("display", div.css("display") === "block" ? "none" : "block");
  $(this.nodeName + " + div").not(div).css("display", "none");
})
```

```css
div {
  display:none;
}
button {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>button 0</button>
<div>text 0</div>
<button>button 1</button>
<div>text 1</div>
<button>button 2</button>
<div>text 2</div>
<button>button 3</button>
<div>text 3</div>
```

Comment: You can use `show` and `hide` instead of setting `css` `display`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, this isn't exactly what I want either. So let's just say there is button 1. I click on the button, and it shows text 1. But when I click button 1 again, I want text1 to be hidden.

Comment: @Tushar _"You can use show and hide instead of setting css display."_ Yes. Either approach should return similar results

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one:**

> Change your CSS as per your requirment :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#button1").click(function() {
        $("#text1").toggle();
        $("#text2").css("display", "none");
        $("#text3").css("display", "none");

      });
      $("#button2").click(function() {
        $("#text2").toggle();
        $("#text1").css("display", "none");
        $("#text3").css("display", "none");
      });
      $("#button3").click(function() {
        $("#text3").toggle();
        $("#text1").css("display", "none");
        $("#text2").css("display", "none");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div style="float:left">
      <input type="button" name="button1" value="Button 1" id="button1">
      <div id="text1" style="display:none">Text 1</div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
      <input type="button" name="button2" value="Button 2" id="button2">
      <div id="text2" style="display:none">Text 2</div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
      <input type="button" name="button3" value="Button 3" id="button3">
      <div id="text3" style="display:none">Text 3</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We are not here to write the full code samples for you, but here is the useful hint: acquire the clicked button's index in the body of `.click()` method and hide all text elements except the one with the same index.

Update: just in case anyone will be interested in my approach to this problem, here is the sample function (assuming all buttons have class 'button' and all texts class 'text'):

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    index = $('.button').index(this);
    $('.text').hide();
    $('.text:eq(' + index + ')').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below modfied code.This is the sample code but you can get idea to figure out your problem

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
      $('.btn').each(function() {
        $(this).next().hide();
      });
      $(this).next().toggle();
    });
  });
</script>

<body>
  <div>
    <button class="btn">Button 1</button>
    <h1 style="display:none">button's 1 text</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn">Button 2</button>
    <h1 style="display:none">button's 2 text</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn">Button 3</button>
    <h1 style="display:none">button's 3 text</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Let me know if you have any doubt

Thanks

Comment: This isn't necessarily what I want. Though, it is helpful. I want, at most, only 1 text to show up at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using bootstrap and jquery

Javascript:

```js
//using jQuery
//show text on button click
$("button").click(function() {
  $("p").addClass("hide");
  switch (this.id) {
    case "button-1":
      $("p#text-1").removeClass("hide");
      break;
    case "button-2":
      $("p#text-2").removeClass("hide");
      break;
    case "button-3":
      $("p#text-3").removeClass("hide");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  } //close switch
}); //end tabs li click
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--jQuery-->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--using Bootstrap-->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="button-1">Show Text 1</button>
<br/>
<p id="text-1" class="hide">Text 1</p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="button-2">Show Text 2</button>
<br/>
<p id="text-2" class="hide">Text 2</p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="button-3">Show Text 3</button>
<br/>
<p id="text-3" class="hide">Text 3</p>
<p class="debug"></p>
```

Hope this helps!